# RequestMappingHandlerMapping registerMapping not binding with RequestBody / HttpEntity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I have a controller loader outside from my Spring Web MVC Project.

Like : `Class myControllerClass = classLoader.loadClass("withfully.packagename.className");`

Let us create an instance of it :

```
Object myControllerClassInstance = myControllerClass.newInstance();
```

then I use the below code snippet to register the endpoint in current running tomcat server (where my current Spring MVC project is already running)

```
    private void addMapping(String urlPath, RequestMethod methodType, String methodName, String consumes,
        String produces) {

    RequestMappingInfo requestMappingInfo = RequestMappingInfo.paths("/someCommon/test1/test2")
.methods(RequestMethod.GET)
.consumes("application/json")
.produces("application/json")
.build();

    for (Method m : myControllerClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(requestMappingInfo, myControllerClassInstance, m);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result** successfully registering endpoint with message

*`INFO: Mapped "{[/someCommon/test1/test2],methods=[GET],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public test.testclass.process.Process userDefinedpackage.someCommon.controller.UserDeployedRestServiceController.someMethod(org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<java.lang.String>) throws java.lang.Exception`*

**Where** signature in  `UserDeployedRestServiceController` was :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="test1/test2",method=RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody test.testclass.process.Process someMethod(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) throws Exception{

System.out.println("We got httpEntity body = "+httpEntity.getBody());
```

**Now** I am trying to hit the URL from outside with json data as request body but getting

***We got httpEntity body = null***

I have tried with `@ResponseBody` as well but no luck + I have also tried with

```
requestMappingHandlerMapping.setDefaultHandler(new UserDeployedServiceRequestHandler());
```

**where**

```
    class UserDeployedServiceRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setStatus (200);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what exactly I am missing. Why request body is always null or empty ?

My application-context is having

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be as simple as the fact that GET requests in general don't support request body. See this SO question: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

FWIW - I have this working using basically

```
RequestMappingInfo mappingInfo = RequestMappingInfo
            .paths("/the/url")
            .methods(RequestMethod.POST)
            .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();

Method meth = ControllerClass.class.getMethod("controllerMethod", RequestType.class));
mappingHandler.registerMapping(mappingInfo, controller, meth);
```

and

```
public class ControllerClass {
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseType> controllerMethod (@RequestBody RequestType request) {
        // service request
        return new ResponseType();
    }
}
```